# Is "the better" a noun phrase in this sentence? How to parse this sentence?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, grammatical-roles

A sentence from [this site](https://www.oregonlive.com/dining/index.ssf/2018/05/portlands_10_best_new_brunches.html) reads ungrammatical.

> On the sweet side, don’t pass up the walnut coffee cake, which is served warm, **the better** to soak up the bourbon-caramel glaze.

Is **the better** a noun phrase in this sentence? Why is it not *better to soak up the bourbon-caramel glaze* as an adverbial? Is the sentence grammatical? What grammar function does the phrase *the better to soak up the bourbon-caramel glaze* serve? Is it a modifier to the main clause?

Comment: It should be noted that, as used above, it's something of an idiom.

Comment: Look here: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+better+to HTH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same use as in *Little Red Riding Hood*, when the wolf says, "The better to eat you with." I'm not entirely certain about the grammar, but I think that the 'the' is being used as an adverb to emphasize 'better'. From Merriam-Webster:

> the, adverb
>
> 1 : than before : than otherwise —used before a comparative, e.g.
>   none *the* wiser for attending
>
> 2a : to what extent, e.g.
>   the sooner *the* better
>
> > b : to that extent, e.g.
> >     the sooner *the* better
>
> 3 : beyond all others, e.g.
>   likes this *the* best

I think that the use in the article is that of the first definition.

Answer (score -1):

The phrase "the better" modifies the state of being warm. It is a comparison of utility of two opposites, warmth contrasted against coolness, by linking the state with more or less efficiency of soaking up the glaze.

> ...which is served warm [as opposed to cool], the better [of the two temperatures] to soak up...

See [this definition](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/all-the-better-to) as "more suitable to".